# The @ in a for loop while using scp

Tags: ant, scp

Please take a look at this line:

```
${server_username}:${server_password}@@{server}:/tmp
```

The double @@ causes problems. Instead of user:pass@server it displays as user:passserver and therefore is unable to connect to the remote ssh server.

How do you tell ant to leave the @ be?

This is my code:

```
<for list="${externalLibs}" param="library"> 
  <sequential>
    <for list="${servers}" param="server"> 
      <sequential>
        <echo> Copying @{library} to @{server} ${server_username}:${server_password}@@@{server}:/tmp/@{library}/${@{library}}/ 
        </echo>
        <scp todir="${server_username}:${server_password}@@@{server}:/tmp/@{library}/${@{library}}/">     
          <fileset dir="/tmp/@{library}/${@{library}}/" /> 
        </scp>
      </sequential> 
    </for>
  </sequential> 
</for>
```

In the echo command, it shows like this:

> Copying LibraryName to
>   myserver.domain.com
>   username:password@{server}:/tmp/LibraryName/LibraryBar

Comment: Causes problems for what?  Who?  How?

Comment: Wish I knew had to do formatting better :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You escape `@` by doubling it, as in `@@`.

So in your case it will be:

```
${server_username}:${server_password}@@@{server}:/tmp
```

BTW, same rule goes for `$` escape, `$$` just prints a `$`.

**In reply to OP's comment**

Example:

```
<property name="server_username" value="user-name"/>
<property name="server_password" value="passwd"/>

<for list="s1.foo.bar,s2.foo.bar,s3.foo.bar" param="server">
  <sequential>
    <echo message="${server_username}:${server_password}@@@{server}:/tmp"/>
  </sequential>
</ac>
```

This produces:

```
 [echo] user-name:passwd@s1.foo.bar:/tmp
 [echo] user-name:passwd@s2.foo.bar:/tmp
 [echo] user-name:passwd@s3.foo.bar:/tmp
```

So, your problem is somewhere else, probably in the loop setup code

Comment: Hi Alexander, it doesn't seem to work for me :-(     It just echo's out @{server}

Comment: @Steve. Post you whole loop setup, because the example here does work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a typo in that line - second last `@` should be changed to `$`:
`${server_username}:${server_password}@${server}:/tmp`

Comment: Also I am assuming that you are using the Ant SCP task

Comment: Sorry Zloi, forgot to mention that the command is enclosed in a for loop.

Comment: Then you should use triple @ as recomended by Alexander Pogrebnyak

Comment: Cannot comment answers from others because of low reputation yet :)

It works for me:

<for list="server1, server2" param="server">
   <sequential>
    <echo>${server_username}:${server_password}@@@{server}:/tmp</echo>
    <scp file="pom.xml" todir="${server_username}:${server_password}@@@{server}:/tmp" trust="true"/>   
   </sequential>
  </for>