# Ant task looping external file and copy some file to each server listed in external file

Tags: ant

I prepared a WLST script that prints all sever names from WebLogic cluster to output file. The output is dynamic and it's content depends of amount of servers - cluster members.
The output file is simple:

> hostname1
>
> hostname2 ..
>
> hostnameN

I need now to prepare the Ant task that will copy one file to each server from the outputfile. As I understand I need to use **Apply** task , because I cannot install additional Ant packages.

Comment: In other words I'm looking how to convert file with all hostnames to propety that I can use in loop <for list="${servers}" param="server">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is , assuming the use of SCP for the deploy, is to run a setup script before running ant deploy target.

Setup has:

1. INPUT= the list of target hosts
2. INPUT= ant properties file that is used in ant.SCP action.
3. OUTPUT= new version of properties reflecting the updated list of target hosts.

Once the setup has run, the abstract deploy step is now concrete and has a list of SCP steps in a loop that will copy to all needed hosts.

Sample SCP syntax..

```
  <scp file="myfile.txt"
       todir="user@somehost:/home/chuck" 
       keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa"
       passphrase="my extremely secret passphrase"
  />
```

Sample loop :

[The @ in a for loop while using scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280858/the-in-a-for-loop-while-using-scp)

Comment: for for loop needs ant-contrib, which is a separate lib

Comment: Thank you Robert for answring my question , actually I have to use a password when connecting scp , but link you provided is very useful. I'm lookig now how to convert file with all hostnames to sometthing like this      <for list="${servers}" param="server">